# How can I get images in react from nodeJS API server

Tags: reactjs

I need to show an image that I uploaded in the node server, I can access the image in the server because I put the file public but I dont know how can import the image in react because when I try to import in a usual way like

```
<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "../../../../../api/uploads/1570230561283padre-e-hija.jpg"} style={imgStyle}/>
```

the response from the server is 404 not found. So how can I fix this?

Thanks :)

Comment: You're probably going to want to look into serving this image file (or images) statically with the built in methods from Express. <https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use  `express.static` function to serve static content

```
//in nodejs

    app.use(express.static('pathToUploadFolder'))

//react js

    <img src="/1570230561283padre-e-hija.jpg" style={imgStyle}/>
```

Comment: can u paste out code snippet and image of folder structure?